# No option selected in two-way binded select dropdowns?

Tags: angular

I'm creating two-way binded `select` dropdowns, using `ngFor`, which are working fine, but when the page loads no `option` is selected. I've tried with `[selected]`, but nothing happens again... Any toughts?

---

Code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let attribute of details.Attributes">
    <tr *ngIf="attribute.IsConfigurator == 'true'">
        <td align="right">{{attribute.PropertyName}}</td>
        <td>
            <select [(ngModel)]="config[attribute.Pid]" (ngModelChange)="updateConfig()" class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let values of attribute.Values; let i = index" value="{{values.Vid}}" [selected]="i == 0">{{values.Value}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the **`ngModel`** value inside the component on **`ngOnInit`**

```
selected : any;
ngOnInit() {
     this.selected = this.attribute.Values[0];
}
```

and then

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected " (ngModelChange)="updateConfig()" class="form-control">
     <option *ngFor="let values of attribute.Values; let i = index" value="{{values.Vid}}">{{values.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can't use `selected` as `ngModel`, since I have 10+ `select` dropdowns in my page, all different...

Comment: even if you use other way you need to have 10 different variables

Answer (score 0):

`[selected]="i == 0"` doesn't work with `[(ngModel)]="config[attribute.Pid]"`

Assign the value that you want have selected to `config[attribute.Pid]` or whatever expression you bind to `ngModel`

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
selected = 'b';
```

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option *ngFor="let item of values" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

will have `b` initially selected.

Comment: I can't use `selected` as `ngModel`, since I have 10+ `select` dropdowns in my page, all different...

Comment: Then use `selected1` to `selected10` or an array. `selected` is just the simples example. `<select [(ngModel)]="selected[0]">` works as well.